# How to setup Bloomberg Terminal on Windows and blpapi with python in WSL2 and connect them together?

Tags: python, blpapi

I am setting up Bloomberg Terminal on Windows machine and blpapi with python on WSL2. Could you please help me connect blpapi to Bloomberg terminal?

I am using this code snippet to establish connection:

```
import blpapi

options = blpapi.SessionOptions()
options.setServerHost('localhost')
options.setServerPort(8194)
session = blpapi.Session(options)
session.start()
```

I am also using python 3.8 and poetry as a package manager. I don't use conda and not planning to use it.

Thank you!